# create an empty branch

Tags: svn

Subversion 1.6 
    Ubuntu 10.4

I have a project with the following repository layout.

```
proj/trunk
proj/branches/new_feature1/
proj/branches/new_feature2/
proj/tags
```

However, I would like to create a small test app, that isn't a new feature. Just just testing a small aspect of the project. I would like to create this test_app on a new branch. However, I don't want to have to copy from trunk to branch. I just want to create a new empty branch so that I can develop this test_app.

Is there any way to do this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `svn mkdir` to create the directory, and then use `svn co` to check it out:

```
svn mkdir http://path/to/svn/repository/branches/experimental_project
svn co http://path/to/svn/repository/branches/experimental_project project
```

Comment: @roboUK, only if you already have the branches folder checked-out.

Comment: You can directly use svn mkdir http://path/to/svn/repository/branches/experimental_project -m"new empty branch"

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to check out your branches, add a new empty branch, `svn add` the new branch then commit.  You could probably do the same from the command line directly into the repo.